# Which tilings does one of Marjorie Rice's pentagons admit?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, polygons, tiling

Consider the following pentagonal tile, where $b=c=d=e$ and $2A+C=D+2E=360$ degrees:

[image]

We know the following tiling, due to Marjorie Rice:

[image]

(a) Is this the only tiling (up to isomorphism), for $A$, $B$ and $E$ generic?

(b) It is easy to see that this tiling is $3$-colorable. How many different $3$-colorings are there, up to isomorphism?

Comment: There seem to be exactly two 3-colorings up to isomorphism.